# How do I find out which argument is invalid when receiving 'The best overloaded match for (...) has some invalid arguments'?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Given a function

```
public static void foo(string bar, int baz) { 

}
```

Visual Studio will display an error *The best overloaded method match for Foo(string,int) has some invalid arguments* when called thusly:

```
string bar;
string baz;
foo(bar, baz);
```

In this example the solution is simple, `baz` should be an `int`.
But how do I find out which of the arguments is invalid?

Comment: you error list should say something like  "Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type X to type Y "

Comment: Why you are looking for invalid Argument..

Comment: @KCdod: thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for! Turn your comment into an answer and I'll accept it...

Comment: @KCdod but the error list is available only when you are running the code, what if I see red underline below the call and try to identify what is the problem? all i get is a tool tip saying the error mentioned by OP. O.O

Comment: @Codeek it is available even in normal mode. activate it by View -> Error List ..

Comment: @KCdod thnx, found it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In such a case visual studio will show that error in `Error List` in following order

```
Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'Type A' to 'TypeB' SourceFIle.Cs Line Column Project
```

If Error View sub window is not enabled, enable it by activating from View menu

> View -> Error List

Hope this would help you